# How to convert unicode byte array to normal string in go

Tags: string, unicode, go, byte

I'm getting the byte array from unix socket and try to print as a string. I just `string(bytes)` and get the following string.

```
{\"Created\":1410263175,\"Id\":\"f4e36130333537c3725e212f78d603742cf3da4b738272f7232338b0d61fa4fb\",\"ParentId\":\"a8a806a76e3e620a6f2172e401847beb4535b072cf7e60d31e91becc3986827e\",\"RepoTags\":[\"\\u003cnone\\u003e:\\u003cnone\\u003e\"],\"Size\":0,\"VirtualSize\":1260903901}\n,
```

How can I remove the escape char `\` and convert unicode char `\u003` into normal string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a JSON string with \u escapes per the JSON specification. The JSON decoder will take care of unescaping the strings.

The code:

```
s := "{\"Created\":1410263175,\"Id\":\"f4e36130333537c3725e212f78d603742cf3da4b738272f7232338b0d61fa4fb\",\"ParentId\":\"a8a806a76e3e620a6f2172e401847beb4535b072cf7e60d31e91becc3986827e\",\"RepoTags\":[\"\\u003cnone\\u003e:\\u003cnone\\u003e\"],\"Size\":0,\"VirtualSize\":1260903901}\n"
var m map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%#v", m)
```

prints the following (minus the white space that I added for readability):

```
map[string]interface {}{
     "Created":1.410263175e+09, 
     "Id":"f4e36130333537c3725e212f78d603742cf3da4b738272f7232338b0d61fa4fb",
     "ParentId":"a8a806a76e3e620a6f2172e401847beb4535b072cf7e60d31e91becc3986827e", 
     "RepoTags":[]interface {}{"<none>:<none>"}, 
     "Size":0, 
     "VirtualSize":1.260903901e+09}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3MNwnQC6_-)</kbd>

The \u escape is not created when converting bytes to a string in Go. It's part of the byte sequence generated by a JSON encoder. The string conversion operator string(byteSlice) converts these bytes to a string as is.

Comment: Thanks @tumahai and you're right. It's a JSON bytes. Can you give a demo to convert bytes to string rather than using map?